# Prove the statement by induction

Tags: induction

Prove that ∀n ∈ N{1},

(1/1!)+(1/2!) + (1/3!) +···+ (1/n!) < 3− [2/(n+1)!]

after suppose it is true for n = k,

so (1/1!)+(1/2!) + (1/3!) +···+ [1/ (n)!]< 3− [2/(k+1)!]

then for n= k+1,
(1/1!)+(1/2!) + (1/3!) +···+ [1/ (k)!] + [1/(k+1)!]< 3− [2/(k+1)!]+[1/(k+1)!] = 3 - [1/(k+1)!]

I proved it is true for n = k+1 by 3-[1/(k+1)!] < 3-[2/(k+2)!]

Is there another way to prove it by induction? something like transform the inequality?

Comment: ???  Having proved it by induction, why would you want **another** way to prove it by induction?  ("Proof by induction" is pretty much "cut and dried"- I can't imagine there  being two *different* ways to prove any given statement by induction.)

Comment: I just wondering if there is another way to prove this inequality. you can say no if you don't have another solution. please read my question not just look at the first and last sentence

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $1/1!+1/2!+1/3!+\cdots1/n!<e-1<2\le3-2/(n+1)!$ for $n\ge1$

Answer (score 0):

You can also transform the Left Hand side like this:
(1/1!)+(1/2!) + (1/3!) +···+ [1/ (k)!] + [1/(k+1)!]

= 3 - [2/(k+1)!]           + [1/(k+1)!]

= 3 - [1/(k+1)!]

= 3 - [(k+2)/(k+2)!]

= 3 - [2/(k+2)!] - [k/(k+1)!] < 3 - [2/(k+2)!]   (what we need to prove for n= k+1)